# List of environments in POSTMAN

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I am working on a POSTMAN collection. Say, I have two separate postman environments with each having URL variables, lets domain1 & domain2. In my initial script in pre-request tab I want to get a list of all the environments available so I can switch them when I need to. How do I get the list of environments?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Christian Bauman. I was able to accomplish by doing following
In postman Pre-request Script tab. The response will contain environment array with object having id, name, owner, uid properties. you can then call by id to get further details of an environment.

```js
let options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.getpostman.com/environments',
  header: {
    'x-api-key': 'PMAK-your own key goes here'
  },
  json: true
};

let envs = [];
pm.sendRequest(options, function(err, response) {
  if (!err) {
    let data = response.json();
    _.forEach(data.environments, function(item) {
      envs.push(item);
    });
    console.log(envs);
  } else {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: What does "PMAK" stand for?

Comment: I had to look for this too. Here you go: https://learning.postman.com/docs/developer/intro-api/#generating-a-postman-api-key. You may need to get a Postman Pro subscription to generate this API key and use their Pro API, but verify. Postman Pro API documentation here: https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/2483749/6mxbxTS#intro

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to select environment from scripts. the closest one can get, is to receive the name of the currently active environment: `pm.environment.name`